# A window into another window

Tags: windows, window-manager

Is there a software that displays a "window" that shows the contents of another window (an actual window of an app/software)?

I have a lot of windows that I like to monitor constantly, for ex., an IP Cam footage, CPU/Disk usage graph/values, a browser window but only a small portion of it.

I could just rearrange (stack/side-by-side) those windows to all show at the same time but resizing is often messes up the default layouts of some apps, and in some cases isn't even possible.

I want a "preview" of each window but only a small portion of them.

E.g.:

[image]

Is there a software that does this?

OS: Windows. License: Any.

Comment: It seems possible from a technical perspective: https://stackoverflow.com/a/911225/480982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature now exists PowerToys: Crop And Lock

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/crop-and-lock

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would probably take some doing to set it up, *enough that it would probably only be worth it for a fixed set of windows* and it will take a lot of digging through the documentation.

### Free Solution

You could use FFMPEG and the [built in GDI screen grabber](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Usebuilt-inGDIscreengrabber) to:

1. Capture a specific window *by title* at a specified frame rate, as in `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title=Calculator ...`
2. Scale &/or crop the video feed from that window as in `... -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -video_size 640x480 ...`
3. You may need to stream each resulting video `... udp://192.168.2.1:6666` using localhost and a different port number for each capture window then
4. Tile or [mosaic the videos](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) from the streams into a new one
5. Use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) to "play" the stream.

Note that it may even be possible to do all of the window captures and the mosaic in a single command - you will need to dig & experiment and possibly reach out to the FFMPEG community for the syntax.

### Paid for Solution

Unreal Streaming Technologies have a set of [components](http://umediaserver.net/components/index.html), *all with limited/trial versions available* that include:

- UScreenCapure: "After the installation of this component you will be able to stream your desktop window or part of it"
- UVideoMixerSource: "This filter receives video streams from other source filters installed in the system, and mixes/switches these streams into one output video stream. ...  The filter comes with configuration utility where you can configure the exact layout of mixed streams as well as various transforms: crop, resize, transparent blending, chroma key etc.."
- Use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) or other stream player to show the stream.